# Error: Negative dimension size caused by subtracting 3 from 1

Tags: neural-network, keras, mnist

The dataset here is the famous MNIST. 
Here's the error: Negative dimension size caused by subtracting 3 from 1 for 'conv2d_8/convolution' (op: 'Conv2D') with input shapes: [?,1,1,64], [3,3,64,128]
Here's the code:

```
model = models.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(28,28, 1)))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
```

I would appreciate to know how can I fix the error, and generally what these type of errors mean.
Thanks everyone.

Comment: Problem might lie around how [`Conv2D`](https://keras.io/layers/convolutional/) works. If you don't set the `padding` argument it will default to `valid`, meaning that the automatic dimensionality reduction that occurs during convolution will be present. If you do that calculation for a `28x28` image with automatic dimensionality reduction with this model, you'll get negative dimensions. To make sure you get the same dimensionality after performing convolution as you input make sure you set `padding=same` while specifying `Conv2D` layers.